# How to fill some fields on form automatically with results from DB

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

Well, I have this function :

```
     function preencherLinhaProduto(obj) {
    $.ajax({type: "POST",
        url: '/pedidoOnline/index.php/Pedidos/pesquisarLinhaProduto',
        async: false,
        data: {
            cd_cpl_tamanho: obj
        },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            var teste = JSON.parse(data);
            //I'm trying to do this way, but isn't working
            var table = $('#tabelaPedido');
            $(table).each(function() {
                $(this).closest('tr').find('.cod_linha').val(teste.id);
                $(this).closest('tr').find('.linha').val(teste.label);
        });
        }
    });
}
```

My search from DB :

```
 public function pesquisarLinhaProduto(){
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->loadModel('ProcuraProdutoPedOnline');
    // Consultando pelo que o usuÃ¡rio estÃ¡ digitando
    $produto = $_REQUEST['cd_cpl_tamanho'];
    $linhas = $this->ProcuraProdutoPedOnline->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array('cd_linha', 'ds_linha'),
            'conditions' => array(
                    'cd_cpl_tamanho' => "$produto"
            )
    ));

    // Formatar resultado
    $result = array();
    foreach ($linhas as $key => $linha) {
        $result[$key]['id'] = (int) $linha['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['cd_linha'];
        $result[$key]['label'] = utf8_encode($linha['ProcuraProdutoPedOnline']['ds_linha']);
    }

    $linhas = $result;
    echo json_encode($linhas);
}
```

What I want ? I want to fill some fields on my form page automatically with the results from the DB ( which is returning with those informations Ok).
How do I do that ?

Comment: Well I don't see a problem here... use the response array in the ajax success function and fill them.

Comment: I added more information , I'm trying like that, but isn't working, any help?

Answer (score -1):

You have the results. You can set the values for the forms to the results as appropriate. Very short example:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $results['firstname'] ?>">
```

If you don't have results, the value will be set blank.

Comment: I added more information , I'm trying like that, but isn't working, any help?

Comment: The question would lead one to reasonably assume he is is trying to populate the value via AJAX.